# Is there a way to hide figure captions when using knitr and pandoc to create docx files?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am using knitr and pandoc to write reports into word (we need to be able to circulate for comments using track changes etc).

It is working very well so far, but I have found that the plots are all coming out with captions at the bottom, and I don't want captions.  While I could just delete them in the word doc, if I can stop them showing in the code it would be better.

So for the following code in markdown:

````
Test test test

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
plot(cars)
```
````

I then run the following code in R:

```
library("knitr")

# Stackoverflow table test 1.html

knit2html("captiontest.rmd")

FILE <- "captiontest"

system(paste0("pandoc -o ", FILE, ".docx ", FILE, ".md"))
```

And the graph, in the word document, has the caption "plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2"

I know I can change this caption, e.g. `{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6, fig.cap='hello'}`, but I thought that `fig.cap=NULL` would make it hidden.  Instead it seems to make the whole plot disappear.

Are plots required to have a caption - do I just have to go through each word doc and delete them manually?  Or is there a way to hide them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kind of a dirty trick, but:

You can set `fig.cap=""` on the chunk in question:

````
Test test test

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6, fig.cap=""}
plot(cars)
```
````

Or, you can set `fig.cap=""` for all chunks at once in an initializing chunk at the beginning of your Rmd document:

````
Test test test

```{r options-chunk} 
opts_chunk$set(fig.cap="")
``` 

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: Ahh sneaky, and useful to be able to set it for all of them at once.  Thank you :)  (I feel like I should have seen to try that!)

Comment: Setting fig.cap to NULL or NA feel like they should intuitively provide the same result.

Comment: I have code (that I modified from someone else last year) that creates nicely numbered captions above my figures. Recently (I don't remember when), my figures ALSO have the caption below them. Why doesn't the `knit.hook` override that: `# number figures with zfn and make a pretty caption
zfn = local({
  i = 0
  function(x) {
    i <<- i + 1
    paste('<b>\n\nFigure ', i, ': ', x, '</b>',sep = '')
    #  wraps your caption in <caption></caption>
  }
})
knit_hooks$set(fig.cap = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(before)
    zfn(options$fig.cap)
})`

Comment: @jessi I think you should open a new question. :)